# How to use .strip on multiple strings?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to remove the brackets and speech marks from the items that I retrieve from the text file, but it only does it for `self.user` but not for `self.passw`. I want to know how I can do it for both.

```
def check(self):
self.credentials = {}
for line in open('Passwords.txt','r'):
    print('line',line)
    self.user, self.passw = line.split(':')
    for i in self.user:
        print(i)
        if i=='{' or i =='"':
            print('i', i)
            self.user=self.user.strip(i)
        else:
            pass


    for j in self.passw:
        print(j)
        if j=='"' or j =='}'or j==' ':
            print('j', j)
            self.passw=self.passw.strip(j)
        else:
            pass


    self.credentials[self.user] = self.passw
    print(self.credentials)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of an input file?

Comment: i have got the main problem sorted.

Answer (score 2):

`.strip()` only removes the characters from the start/end of the string. Your algorithm goes through the string character by character, and everytime it encounters one of the unwanted characters, it tries stripping that from the entire string. Of course, this only works at all if all the bad characters surround the good ones, and it's extremely inefficient.

A better way would be to contruct a new string only from those characters that pass the test:

```
self.user = ''.join([c for c in self.user if c not in '{}"'])
```

or to use a regex (which I'd prefer):

```
self.user = re.sub(r'[{}"]+', '', self.user)
```

Note that I added `}` to the set of unwanted characters, assuming you want to remove that one, too.

Comment: Would be able to add a space to the blacklist, I have tried to remove space but that doesn't get removed.

Comment: Sure, just add that to the string/regex.

Comment: UserName bayley
PassWord bayley
line {"bayley": "bayley"}

bayley 
 bayley

Username or password is incorrect
This is what i get in the shell, and there is a space before password

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. You're parsing something that suspiciouly looks like JSON. Please show the actual input and your desired output (edit your question to do so).